# attribute assignment in a callback does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have HABTM models `Client` and `Book`. `Client` model has a bookshelf_color attribute to indicate whether a client has a full set of books, part of them or none of them. Once the books on a bookshelf change, a callback `set_bookshelf_color` is supposed to reflect the change.

The question is why do I have to prefix bookshelf_color assignment in a private callback below with `"self."` to make it to work (as it does not otherwise)?

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :books, autosave: true, uniq: true,
    after_add: :set_bookshelf_color, after_remove: :set_bookshelf_color

  attr_accessible :id, :book_ids, :bookshelf_color

  private

    def set_bookshelf_color(book)
      if Book.pluck(:abbr).map{|b| books.map(&:abbr).map(&:to_s).include?(b.to_s)}.all?
        self.bookshelf_color = "green"
      elsif Book.pluck(:abbr).map{|b| books.map(&:abbr).map(&:to_s).include?(b.to_s)}.any?
        self.bookshelf_color = "yellow"
      else
        self.bookshelf_color = "red"
      end
    end
  # /private
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, your model properties are just instance variables behind the scenes – all we're doing when we interact with them is calling the getter and setter methods set up by `attr_accessor`. When we write `instance.bookshelf_color = "red"` we're sending the method `bookshelf_color=`, with the argument `"red"`, to the receiver, `instance`.

Cool. What happens when we write just `bookshelf_color = "red"`?

In Ruby, bareword assignment is used to define local variables. Putting `name = "value"` in a method definition will define `name` in the local scope, rather than calling the `name=` method on `self`, even if that method exists.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  def set_bar(val)
    bar = val
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.set_bar "baz"
f.bar # still nil
```

If I had specified an explicit receiver, `self.bar = val`, Ruby would have known I wanted to send `self` the method `bar=`, which would have had the desired result.

There's some good further reading on the joys of `self`, and why you should use it, over on [Joe Yates' Blog](http://titusd.co.uk/2012/01/16/ruby-bareword-assignment-and-method-calls-with-implicit-self/).

Comment: Thanks, that explains it - it just looked strange to me at first.